# How can I allocate Array of Structure with malloc() in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, structure

I want to allocate array of structure but I'm getting this error with GCC:

> st.c: In function ‘main’:
>   st.c:20:4: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct employeeStruct’ from type ‘void *’
>    *sp=malloc(sizeof(struct productStruct)*n);

And this is my struct and pointer:

```
struct productStruct
{
        unsigned int ID;
        unsigned long int serialnumber;
        char name[40];
};

struct productStruct *sp;
```

And after getting n variable from user at main function:(Im getting error for this line)

```
*sp=malloc(sizeof(struct *productStruct)*n);
```

I don't know maybe this is type casting error but I could not fix it.
Thanks for your attention

Comment: just `sp=malloc(sizeof(struct *productStruct)*n);` don't de'reference you'll be OK

Comment: `sp` is the pointer and `*sp` dereferenced pointer .

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think he rather wants this: `sp = malloc(sizeof(struct productStruct) * n)`

Comment: yeah, just realized that strange stuff inside. even better: `sp=malloc(sizeof(*sp)*n);` so if type changes the `malloc` remains coherent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

Use `sp` not `*sp` and reserve the size of the struct, not the size of a pointer to the struct (if you really want an array of structs instead of pointers):

`sp=malloc(sizeof(struct productStruct)*n);`

Comment: Less error prone to do: `sp = malloc(sizeof *sp * n);`

Comment: To be fair, I've always found `sizeof struct type_t` more readable, granted your way of doing it makes refactoring easier, due to the independence of the type name.